# Using sed on Bash Command

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to get a list of devices on my `linux` box from normal bash commands in a script.  I've used the following however it isn't working.  Ideally, I'd like to get all `sd*` and `nvme` devices into an array.  This is what I have tried:

```
lsblk --nodeps | sed -n '/sd\.*/p'
lsblk --nodeps | sed '/(sd | nv)\.*/p'
lsblk --nodeps | sed -n 's/^([a-z0-9]+?).*/\1/'
lsblk --nodeps | sed -n '/^.*?/p'
lsblk --nodeps | sed '/^(.+?)\s*/p'
lsblk --nodeps | sed '/^(s.+?|n.+?)?)\s*/p'
```

This is the starting syntax:

```
$ lsblk --nodeps
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
sdb       8:16   1  57.8G  0 disk
nvme0n1 259:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
```

So I want to regex for **sd*** and **nvme**, without the trailing spaces.

Any insight appreciated how I can get drives into an array.

Comment: You realize you can get a list of block devices from `/dev`? You don't need `lsblk` for the job at all.

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob; cd /dev; disks=( sd* nvme* )` and there you are, you get an array named `disks` with, in your case, three entries.

Comment: Or, to get easy-to-parse output from `lsblk`, you can do something like `readarray -t disks < <(lsblk -nr --output NAME | egrep '^(sd|nvme)')`. No reason to fight to parse a table when you can just ask for a format that's easier-to-parse than a table.

Comment: ...eh, going to migrate the above two comments into an answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that `sed` could parse and return items.

Comment: "parse" is an awfully strong word for what `sed` does. But I'm not saying you can't use it; I'm saying it's simultaneously overkill (having text-editing tools you don't need) and underpowered (lacking filesystem-inspection capabilities or the like).

Comment: OK also to be clear, I'm looking for devices, not partitions.  that's why I went for `lsblk` to find devices.

Comment: Fair. In that case you might want to use an extglob. I'll extend my answer.

Comment: BTW, looking a little closer at your sed expressions -- `+?` and `*?`, to make globs non-greedy, are trying to use PCRE functionality that POSIX-standard regular expressions don't support. Similarly, `\s` is more portably written as `[[:space:]]`; some popular implementations do support `\s`, but it's nonstandard and they aren't required to.

Comment: Again, I'm not a `bash` person, and I thought sed had parsing of individual lines.  But we have gone the `lsblk` way.  I even checked the options for `lsblk` to see what it could output.  I didn't catch the `NAME` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Making `lsblk` Output Easier To Parse

`lsblk` can be told to suppress a header line, and to emit only the specific pieces of data you care about -- in this case, device names.

If you have a listing with nothing but device names, `grep` is the easiest tool to use to parse them; but to add an additional rule (in this case, discarding partitions), `awk` comes into play.

Thus:

```
readarray -t disks < <(lsblk -dnr --output NAME | grep '^(sd|nvme)')
```

---

#### Filtering `/dev/disk/by-id` Yourself

For the stubborn, to show that it can be done:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
declare -A results=( )
devices=( /dev/disk/by-id/!(*-part*) )
for device in "${devices[@]}"; do
  target=$(readlink -f "$device")
  results[${target#/dev/}]=1
done
disks=( "${!results[@]}" )
declare -p disks # print the resulting array
```

Comment: ```
[Sat Jun 25 19:00:26 rich@server1 /dev] declare -p disks
declare -a disks='([0]="nvme0" [1]="nvme0n1" [2]="sda" [3]="sda1" [4]="sda2" [5]="sdb" [6]="sdb1" [7]="sdb2")'
[Sat Jun 25 19:00:26 rich@server1 /dev] echo $disks
nvme0
```

Comment: `echo "${disks[@]}"` to print all elements of the array -- when you `echo $disks` it prints only `${disks[0]}`. (That's true for _all_ arrays in bash; if you're accustomed to different behavior, you aren't really using arrays).

Comment: `nvme0 nvme0n1 sda sda1 sda2 sdb sdb1 sdb2`  Still has partitions.

Comment: Fair 'nuff. One _could_ do more magic to distinguish dependent devices (devfs and sysfs let you do everything lsblk does yourself -- they're where it gets its data), but it's work.

Comment: The `nvme` drives not showing up, as the partitions have convoluted endings.  `declare -a disks='([0]="sda" [1]="sdb")'`

Comment: The comment you just added is responding to a version of the answer that was already gone. Please refresh.

Comment: Best so far was `lsblk -dnr --output NAME`.  I'm unfamiliar with these instructions, and `sed`.

Comment: Note that if you're not using `readarray`, `mapfile` or similar, your result isn't really an array. `array=( $(...) )` can generate an array, [but it's buggy and best avoided](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29).

Comment: `readarray` seems like it's working fine.  Cheers